# Error: The object is dependent on column 'Id'. (EF one to one mapping without navigation property in dependant)

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am creating `One-To-One relationship` without navigation property in dependant entity as following.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    // StudentReport is optional
    modelBuilder.Entity<Student>() 
        .HasOptional(t => t.StudentReport) 
        .WithRequired();
}

public class Student
{
......

public virtual StudentReport StudentReport{ get; set; }

}

public class StudentReport
{ 
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string RollNumber { get; set; }
    public string StudentType { get; set; }
}
```

However, when i run my application (Database creation) i get the following error

> An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in
>   EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: The object 'PK_dbo.StudentReport' is dependent
>   on column 'Id'.

What could be wrong here?

Comment: Could you show the code that is throwing the exception?

Comment: Is this when creating a new database or while changing an existing one by migrations?

Comment: By changing an existing one by migrations.